# Sending mail using Office 365 in zend framework fail

Tags: php, zend-framework, office365

I am working on a zend framework version 1 which is an extremely old project. I had to implement a email feature on that project and for local development mailtrap was doing completely okay but when it was time to host it on live i wanted to use ***office365*** but gives me an issue.

```
function sendUserEmail($toEmail, $fromEmail, $subject, $body)
{
    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
    $mail->setFrom($fromEmail);
    $mail->addTo($toEmail);
    $mail->setSubject($subject);
    $mail->setBodyText($body);

    // Retrieve SMTP configuration from the application configuration
    $config = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap');
    $smtpConfig = $config->getOptions()['mail']['transport'];

    // Set up SSL configuration
    $ssl = !empty($smtpConfig['ssl']) ? $smtpConfig['ssl'] : null;

    $smtpOptions = [
        'auth' => 'login',
        'username' => office365email,
        'password' => office365password,
        'ssl' => null,
        'port' => 587,
    ];

    // Create an SMTP transport using the provided host and SMTP options
    $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($smtpConfig['host'], $smtpOptions);
    // Send the email using the configured transport
    return $mail->send($transport);
}
```

This is the function that i use send email. It works for sendgrid, mailtrap and other but only doesn't work for ***office365***

I have set ***SSL*** null becuase if i use "TLS" it says "Couldn't connect via tls" and when i put "SSL" it couldn't open socket.

The main error message is
***504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type***

Comment: is your office 365 tenant configured to support basic authentication for smtp? this is something microsoft has been changing defaults for so you may need to make changes to your ms account to have this work.

Comment: Hmmm if the code base is extremely old, then how old is the SSL implementation? The CA cert database?

Comment: @symcbean Sry i don't understand. For mail feature to work should site be https?

Comment: @TZHX but it works in laravel application

Comment: No but I expect even Microsoft would require STARTTLS (i.e. SSL for SMTP) before authentication.